# Can I use special characters in a Gitolite repo name?

Tags: gitolite

Is it possible to create a repo called `Pavilhão_Valença` in gitolite3 v3.6.6-2?

I wanted to try it but I'm scared of breaking something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried creating a repo called `users/me/ãtest` on my Gitolite 3 instance, and I got this error:

```
FATAL: suspicious characters loitering about 'create users/me/ãtest'
```

so no, you aren't able to create repos with such Unicode characters in the names by default.

Looking at the source code, that error is caused by [this line](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell#L178), which refers to [this pattern](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L49), which only contains non-accented letters, numbers, and some symbols.

There shouldn't be any issue with using such characters in filenames for the underlying filesystem (at least it worked fine on my ext4 filesystem on Debian Linux), so if that regex was to be changed, it would Probably Work<sup>TM</sup>.

According to [this post on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gitolite/FATAL$3A$20suspicious$20characters$20loitering|sort:date/gitolite/h2v4psBUMk8/Ta_ae8dz2WMJ), you can copy that line into your `~/.gitolite.rc` and modify it there.